# Add dot after chapter number in ToC (`memoir` class)

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\chapter{Third}
\end{document}
```

I want to add period after chapter number in ToC (only in ToC). I have been searching everywhere but I couldn't find a working answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you did not read the manual hard enough ;-)

Section 9.2.2 describes that the K number (K being chapter, section what ever), is being typeset in a box of a certain width, in a fashion similar to

```
BOX{\cftKname \cftKpresnum SNUM\cftKaftersnum\hfil} \cftKaftersnumb
```

where SNUM is the K number in question.

Thus

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{.}
```

solves your problem